# 2 csv file in a for loop, output one csv file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I’ve got 2 csv files the first one (station.csv) has got two columns with latitude and longitude, the second (catalog.csv has got 5 columns and also two with latitude and longitude) i’ve managed to calculate the distance between two points with geopy.distance.distance but when I try to iterate through the files to get the distance of every lat-long in the catalog.csv from the station ot gives me always the last value. Ideally the output would be adding as many columns as the stations so for every point in the catalog.csv i’d have a distance with the given station.

Expected output
ctlg.csv with the original data and 29 new columns with distance from each sts.

timeUtc,latitude,longitude,magnitude,distance_sts1....29

```
    import pandas as pd  
    import geopy.distance  
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame  
    ctlg1 = pd.read_csv('ctlg1.csv', sep=',')  
    sts = pd.read_csv('stations.csv', sep=',')   
    for row1 in sts.iterrows():  
      coords_1 = (row1[1][1], row1[1][2])  
      for row2 in ctlg1.iterrows():  
      coords_2 = (row2[1][4], row2[1][5])  
      distance = geopy.distance.distance((coords_1),(coords_2))  
      data = [distance]    
      df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
      df.to_csv("ctlg.csv")
```

Comment: Could you also add your attempted code

Comment: Also add sample data and expected output

Comment: please fix the indentation

Answer (score 1):

After calculating the distance inside the nested `for` loop you are assigning it to variable `data`.

But after each iteration, the value of data is overwritten. So naturally, the final value of the `data` will be the distance corresponding to the last coordinate.